# Command to create a disk image in which bad sectors are replaced by zeroes

Tags: debian, dd, disk-image

From time to time I have HDDs and microSD cards which have bad sectors.

I realized that all `photorec`, `(ext/ntfs/...)undelete` and `dd` fail or are incredible slow.

[Other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77490400/how-do-i-clone-a-disk-drive-with-bad-sectors) seem to have the same problem with other tools (in this particular post Clonezilla and EaseUS Disk Copy Pro).

The reason is all those tools fail when there is a bad sector at all or they try to read bad sectors many times instead of trying it only 1 or 2 times. If a tool tries to read a bad sector many times it may take days for the tool to finish.

I have written my own script which creates a disk image and it replaces bad sectors by zeroes. After that I can run any recovery tool I like on it with no problems. (I read the image from the damaged disk and store it as a file on a healthy disk.)

Is it possible to do the same on the Linux command line using common Linux commands?

After two failed reads a bad sector should be replaced by zeroes in the image. Also the buffer size (similar to `dd`'s `bs` option) should be big enough to get max. read/write performance.